# How to observe swipe event (cell position) of a UITableViewCell by Key-Value-Observer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, key-value-observing, ios7.1

I have a `UITableView` and custom `UITableViewCell`. When I swipe the cell in order to delete it, I have to exactly get informed about the position of the cell (view) in order to adjust its content accordingly. Therefore, I planned to use the key-value-observer (KVO) in the `UITableViewCell` class.

**Add Observer**

```
[self.contentView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"center" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];
```

**Observer**

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"center"]) {
        NSLog(@"KVO: %@", change);
    }
}
```

But I get no notification. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Why not overload the `willTransitionToState:` method?

Comment: This I already tried. But I need the exact position of the cell, when it is being swiped. the `willTransitionToState` only notifies the start and end of the swipe.